# How to kill a thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, tcp

I have a thread in `Winform`. After I exit the application or shut down the server console application, the thread continues to work. Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    StreamReader sr;
    StreamWriter sw;
    TcpClient connection;
    string name;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 5000);
        sr = new StreamReader(connection.GetStream());
        sw = new StreamWriter(connection.GetStream());
        ChatterScreen.Text = "Welcome, please enter your name";
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Thread t2 = new Thread(Reader);
        //t2.IsBackground = true;
        //t2.Start(connection);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Reader,connection);//How do i kill this thread
        name = InputLine.Text;
    }

    string textinput;
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textinput = InputLine.Text;
        sw.WriteLine(name+":"+textinput);
        sw.Flush();
    }

    string msg;
    string allMessages;
    public void Reader(object o)
    {
        TcpClient con = o as TcpClient;
        if (con == null)
            return;
        while (true)
        {
            msg = sr.ReadLine() + Environment.NewLine;
            allMessages += msg;
            Invoke(new Action(Output)); // An exception is thrown here constantly. sometimes it is thrown and sometimes if i quite the server application , the winform application freezes.
            Invoke(new Action(AddNameList));
        }
    }

    public void Output()
    {
        ChatterScreen.Text = allMessages;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no safe way to kill a thread without doing a bit of work: you should never call Abort on a thread; what you need to do is to detect in the thread that it is required to terminate prior to completing its normal execution and then you need to tell it how to carry out this termination.

In C# the easiest way to do this is to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_BackgroundWorker) which is essentially an object that executes code in a background thread; it is similar to calling invoke, except you have more control over the thread's execution. You start the worker by calling RunWorkerAsync() and you instruct it to cancel by calling RunWorkerAsync(). After calling RunWorkerAsync(), the CancellationPending property of the background worker is set to true; you watch for this change in your code (i.e. in your while loop) and when it is true you terminate (i.e. exit your while loop)

```
while (!CancellationPending )
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Personally I do all threading through BackgroundWorkers because they are easy to understand and offer easy ways to communicate between background and main threads

Comment: but if i use backgroundworker, i have to re-write my code and do many changes..  couldnt i simply , put the while loop in try and catch and when i shut down the server, the catch  will prevent the application from crashing

Comment: "i have to re-write my code and do many changes" - that's called software engineering I'm afraid: do something the wrong way, find out what the right way is, use that technique in the future. Using a BackgroundWorker is a solid and safe way to terminate a thread; wrapping a try catch around your loop may well appear to do what you want it to but in my opinion it's a hack.

Comment: Crystal clear B Tyler. so i should use BackgroundWorker instead of invoke(SomeMethod);

Comment: Yes, I would always go for a BackgroundWorker over and Invoke.

Answer (score -1):

You should put an [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) in your Reader function. Instead of while(true), do while(!mManualReset.WaitOne(0)).  Then before you quit the program do mManualReset.Set()  This will let the thread exit gracefully.

Comment: @Hellfrost AutoResetEvent is used for thread synchronization, so this IS a good way to interact with threads. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @SW it's purpose is synchronization, not signalling. what you are suggesting is both inefficient and incorrect.  use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx

Comment: If you look at the waitone constructor that takes an int, 0 IS a special case

Comment: If millisecondsTimeout is zero, the method does not block. It tests the state of the wait handle and returns immediately

Comment: 1. WaitOne is a method not a constructor. 2. it still has a fairly high performance cost. 3. Again, it's not a signalling mechanism

Comment: 1 yup that's what I ment, 2 doubt it, 3 yes it is

Comment: "The caller of this method blocks until the current instance receives a signal or a time-out occurs. Use this method to block until a WaitHandle receives a signal from another thread, such as is generated when an asynchronous operation completes. For more information, see the IAsyncResult interface."